# When distance nonincreasing map is an isometry

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Let $f: M \to M$ be a distance nonincreasing map between a closed Riemannian manifold $M$
and $f$ is homotopic to the idendity map. Is it then $f$ an isometry?

Answer (score 11):

Combine the following:

1. If $X$ is a compact metric space, then any surjective distance non-increasing map $X\to X$ is an isometry (see e.g. Burago-Burago-Ivanov's "A course in metric geometry", theorem 1.6.15, or prove yourself-this is easy).
2. If a map of closed manifolds has nonzero $\mathbb Z_2$-degree, the map is surjective (because every point in the target has odd number of preimages).

Answer (score 3):

If $f$ is not an isometry then $Vol(f(M))< f(M)$, which then implies that $deg(f)=0$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Why if $f$ is not an isometry, then $Vol (f(M)< vol (M)$?For example, a covering map is distance nonincreasing and $Vol f(M)=vol (M)$, but a covering map is not an isometry. Of course a covering map is not homotopic to the idendity map.

Comment: In your example with covering map, it is not a local isometry from the manifold to itself. To see why volume goes down, look for instance, at small balls: $f(B(x,R))\subset B(f(x),R)$ and one of this inclusions is proper. Alternatively, look at the map $f\times f: M^2\to M^2$ and show that this map strictly reduces volume by considering images of the subsets of the form $\{(x,y): d(x,y)\le R\}\subset M^2$.

Comment: @xiaoyang, Covering map is not distance nonincreasing. Look at 2 to 1 map from $S^1$ to itself.

Comment: Hi, why covering map is not distance nonincreasing? I think any submetry is distance nonincreasing?

Comment: Just try to define carefully what you mean and you will see.

Comment: Hi, J. Ge, the $2$ to $1$ map from $S^1$ to itself is not a "Riemannian" covering map if the metric on $S^1$ is fixed. I agree with you, it is neither distance non-increasing, nor distance non-decreasing. But if we use two different metrics on $S^1$ such that this map is a Riemannian covering map (just pull back the metric), then it is distance non-increasing. Then it is not a local isometry from $S^1$ to itself, of course. That is what Misha means?

Comment: @XiaoyangChen I am still not sure about why $Vol(f(M)) < Vol(M)$? I agree that in some sense $f$ "locally" reduces volume, i.e there exists closed balls of radius $R$ such that $Vol(f(B(x,R)) < Vol((B(f(x),R))$ (because of the strict containment like you mentioned).  However, the inequality $Vol(f(M)) < Vol(M)$ is a global property, and I do not see how the local property implies it.

Comment: (A-priori the "missing" parts in $(B(f(x),R)$ could be covered by the images of other points. For example if $f$ is surjective. In this case, it *is* true that $f$ must be an isometry (see Igor's answer) but this is not trivial). Would you mind elaborating?

Comment: @Misha (Please see my 2 previous comments above, I accidentally directed them to another user). Actually I am not sure that even the "local argument" above holds. It is possible that balls of  the same radius around *different* points will have different volumes (this depends on the curvature in the respective neighbourhoods, which can be different, since we do not assume the manifold has a constant curvature)